# How to stop Rails.autoloaders.logger?

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails-6

I tried

```
  Rails.autoloaders.logger=0
  Rails.autoloaders.logger.stop
```

and a bunch of other stuff in the console, where it initiated it with

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting it to `nil`?

You could also try redirecting the logger to null:

```
logger = Logger.new("/dev/null")
Rails.autoloaders.logger = logger
```